# How to get the info about the incoming call when the calling party starts

Tags: avaya, jtapi

We need to get the info about the incoming call when the calling party starts to hear the welcome message from IVR. Could you please advise how can we achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged that question with [jtapi] I assume you would like to use it.

You didn't mention where you would like to receive or how to use that information so I can give you only a brief overview.

If you need it in the IVR and it is a Avaya Experience Portal then you just add the CTI integration to your project and use the CTI Call Info node to have access to call data.

Or you can develop custom application in Java with JTAPI. You start monitoring IVR incoming extensions and when a new call is answered you store call data and the IVR script can get this data via web service calls for example.